# Compare Booleans Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I make my textview in android generate a Boolean table please, since it gives me an error when adding in Kotlin?

It did not directly compare Booleans, since the textview does not directly let me use it to accomplish my goal of generating Boolean tables

```
package com.example.user.herramientaslogica
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.TextView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import org.w3c.dom.Text
    import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private val VALUES = booleanArrayOf(true, false)
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val textview:TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview) as TextView

            for (a in VALUES)

            {
                for (b in VALUES)
                {
                    for (c in VALUES)
                        for (d in VALUES)
                        {
                            for (e in VALUES)
                            {
                                for (f in VALUES)
                                {
                                    textview.setText (a + b + c + d + d + e + f )
                                    )
         textview.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
        }

                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun or(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return x || y
    }
    fun and(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return x && y
    }
    fun xor(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return x xor y
    }
    fun conditional(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return !(x && y)
    }
    fun bicontional(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return x == y
    }
    fun disequal(x:Boolean, y:Boolean):Boolean {
        return x != y
    }
```

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve ?

Comment: Achieve generate a table similar to this
https://mathpullzone-8231.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/truth-table-example1-compound3.png

Comment: Ok, so you want to generate the table. Now, what is the exact issue ? and how would you show the entire table in a single textview ?

Comment: It is not possible to show the textview, why can not I compare the Booleans directly from the textview, why generate an error, do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: @KevinPaúlMontealegreMelo start simple and proceed step by step ... first of all, you are creating an array with 2 booleans (true and false respectively); try to output with Log.d() code, see its values ... then make 1 loop only, and see what you get ... and then continue incrementally ... from reading your code, I've no clue what are you trying to have, you've like 6 nested loops over the same array mmm ...

Comment: There is no way to fix my code that I made without using BooleanArray?